# When using DART FFI to get the result of a C++ function, the result varies on every executions! Why?

Tags: c++, dart, ffi, mingw-w64

Using the internet and ChatGPT as a reference, I created the code below, and it compiled without any problems.

However, when I run it repeatedly, the result was not consistent.

C++ Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int* get_int_array(int size);

int* get_int_array(int size) {
        
        std::vector<int> vec(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            vec[i] = i;
        }
        int* arr = vec.data();
        
        std::cout << "C++ Result" << std::endl;
        for (int i =0; i< size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << ",";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        
        return arr;
}

// g++ -shared -lstdc++ -o user_func.dll user_func.cpp -Wl,--output-def,user_func.def,--out-implib,libuser_func.a
```

Dart Code

```
import 'dart:ffi';

void main() {
  final path = './user_func.dll';
  final _lib = DynamicLibrary.open(path);

  // int* get_int_array(int size)
  final getIntPtr = _lib.lookupFunction<Pointer<Int32> Function(Int32),
      Pointer<Int32> Function(int)>('get_int_array');

  final length = 5;
  final ptr = getIntPtr(length);
  final array = ptr.asTypedList(length);
  print('\nDart Result');
  print(ptr);
  print(array);
}
```

I think it's because of a pointer problem or sync, but I can't guess the exact reason.

If I run it with length=20, I did it 10 times and all 10 times the results were same.

C:\opencv\pjt\vector\vec>dart bin/vec.dart
C++ Result
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,

Dart Result
Pointer: address=0x250d61bae70
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

---

But if I set length=5, the result was different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKTvK.png)

Comment: You have undefined behavior.  `vec` is destroyed at the end of the function which means the pointer you return points to nothing anymore.

Comment: Also, Pro Tip, don't use ChatGPT to code.  It doesn't know how to code.  All it knows is how to do is guess which word should come next.  If ChatGPT could write code, the programmers that wrote it wouldn't be employed anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem was that I didn't understand vectors in C++ and asked chatGPT to tell me how to send vector values to dart.I have one more question. As Length(final length = 5) gets longer in my case, the value in c++ matches the value in dart, is this simply a result of how the OS manages memory?

Comment: Probably. When the vector is destroyed it doesn't clear the memory, so if nothing else has access to that chunk of memory those old value will still be there.  You **cannot** rely on that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The vector auto frees its data when going out of the scope before returning from the c++ function and you are returning a pointer to is freed data which is undefined behaviour!

To get around this allocate the memory buffer with `new` or `malloc` inside `get_int_array` and export another function that takes a pointer and frees it with the appropriate function.

In dart after you get the pointer and is finished with it call the free method to avoid memory leaks